# Group date by month in Pivot table using data from MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, excel, group-by, pivot-table

This is my pivot table and I have sales amount from 6 months. I want to group these dates by month but the group button is disabled/not allowing me to do so.

[image]

Comment: If the group button is disabled, then at least one value within the source table is not a date. You have to check that.

Comment: I have checked it twice. Even other data in pivot table not allowing me to group.

Comment: Is this data in power pivot or in excel sheet?